# fish alternatives for [[ pattern tests ]]

Tags: fish

Trying fish, I am stuck on some bash conditionals using `[[ ... ]]`.

It looks like `[ ... ]` is the usual thing, but I'm stuck on pattern and regular expression tests:

```
[[ "$PATH" =~ "$1" ]]
[[ $localVM =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]
```

How do I do those in fish?

Answer (score 3):

use the [`string match` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html)

```
if string match -q -r $pattern $var
  echo yes
else
  echo no
end
```